# How are variable names chosen in type signatures inferred by GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When I play with checking types of functions in Haskell with `:t`, for example like those in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535729/understanding-function-types), I tend to get results such as:

```
Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
(Ord a, Num a, Ord a1, Num a1) => a -> a1 -> a
(Num t2, Num t1, Num t, Enum t2, Enum t1, Enum t) =>  [(t, t1, t2)]
```

It seems that this is not such a trivial question - how does the Haskell interpreter pick literals to symbolize typeclasses? When would it choose `a` rather than `t`? When would it choose `a1` rather than `b`? Is it important from the programmer's point of view?

Comment: The naming scheme for type variables is not at all important from the programmer's point of view.

Comment: But just out of plain curiosity - why specifically t and not a? There must be some explanation for that...

Comment: AFAIK it's similar to how sometimes people will use `x` when referring to a generic unknown number and other times they'll use `n`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519964/how-does-ghci-pick-names-for-type-variables

Comment: @Niemand That's a question for someone who has worked on the GHC type inference mechanism, which might be hard to come by. It's largely arbitrary and you can ignore it, but being curious is good and I hope someone answers the question.

Comment: Maybe someone from GHC will come by :D

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't explain why `Enum` seems to lead to `t` being chosen whereas otherwise `a` is chosen.

Comment: Coming from an ML background, people there tend to use a, b, c, ...(like alpha, beta)  for type parameters, and t (like tau) for types themselves (we use modules a lot to distinguish them). These letters (and their greek equivalents) are used in the literature more or less that way iirc. So one may consider `t` as more likely to be a monomorphic or a main type, and `a`, `b` ... as a type parameter.

Answer (score 8):

The *names* of the type variables aren't significant. The type:

```
Eq element => element -> [element] -> Bool
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Some names are simply easier to read/remember.

Now, how can an inferencer choose the best names for types?

*Disclaimer:* I'm absolutely *not* a GHC developer. However I'm working on a type-inferencer for Haskell in my bachelor thesis.

During inferencing the names chosen for the variables aren't probably that readable. In fact they are almost surely something along the lines of `_N` with `N` a number or `aN` with `N` a number.

This is due to the fact that you often have to "refresh" type variables in order to complete inferencing, so you need a fast way to create new names. And using numbered variables is pretty straightforward for this purpose.

The names *displayed* when inference is completed can be "pretty printed". The inferencer can rename the variables to use `a`, `b`, `c` and so on instead of `_1`, `_2` etc.

The trick is that most operations have explicit type signatures. Some definitions require to quantify some type variables (`class`, `data` and `instance` for example).
All these names that the user explicitly provides can be used to display the type in a better way.

When inferencing you can somehow keep track of where the fresh type variables came from, in order to be able to rename them with something more sensible when displaying them to the user.
An other option is to refresh variables by adding a number to them. For example a fresh type of `return` could be `Monad m0 => a0 -> m0 a0` (Here we know to use `m` and `a` simply because the `class` definition for `Monad` uses those names). When inferencing is finished you can get rid of the numbers and obtain the pretty names.

In general the inferencer will try to use names that were explicitly provided through signatures. If such a name was already used it might decide to add a number instead of using a different name (e.g. use `b1` instead of `c` if `b` was already bound).

There are probably some other ad hoc rules. For example the fact that tuple elements have like `t`, `t1`, `t2`, `t3` etc. is probably something done with a custom rule. In fact `t` doesn't appear in the signature for `(,,)` for example.

Comment: While experimenting a little, I've noticed that in addition to with tuples, type names starting with `t` get used for things formed out of pure lambda expressions with no named functions used, e.g. `:t \x y -> x y`. So maybe it's somehow the default used when there is no real name available.

Comment: Heh `t`s are used with `:t \x y z -> (x,y,z)` but *not* with `:t \x y z -> (,,) x y z`, which borrows the variables from `(,,)`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, my partial answer and your comments seem somewhat related. There seems to be something going on with certain syntactic forms.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed, but not all, e.g. `\x -> do f <- x; f` uses the same type variables as its official desugaring `\x -> x >>= \f -> f`, which seem inherited from `(>>=)`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I think your hypothesis that `t` is the default is almost certainly right. Why that default "sticks" to the arithmetic sequence forms through the translation I really couldn't say.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Note that type inferencer is performed *before* desugaring (see [here](http://www.aosabook.org/en/ghc.html)). This means that the type inferencer has specific rules for the `do` syntax as well as enumerations, list-comprehensions etc. It's quite possible that they use this knowledge to display better type variables.

Answer (score 3):

[How does GHCi pick names for type variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519964/how-does-ghci-pick-names-for-type-variables) explains how many of these variable names come about. As Ganesh Sittampalam pointed out in a comment, something strange seems to be happening with arithmetic sequences. Both the Haskell 98 report and the Haskell 2010 report indicate that

```
[e1..] = enumFrom e1
```

GHCi, however, gives the following:

```
Prelude> :t [undefined..]
[undefined..] :: Enum t => [t]

Prelude> :t enumFrom undefined
enumFrom undefined :: Enum a => [a]
```

This makes it clear that the weird behavior has nothing to do with the `Enum` class itself, but rather comes in from some stage in translating the syntactic sequence to the `enumFrom` form. I wondered if maybe GHC wasn't *really* using that translation, but it really is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module X (aoeu,htns) where
aoeu = [undefined..]
htns = enumFrom undefined
```

compiled using `ghc -ddump-simpl enumlit.hs` gives

```
X.htns :: forall a_aiD. GHC.Enum.Enum a_aiD => [a_aiD]
[GblId, Arity=1]
X.htns =
  \ (@ a_aiG) ($dEnum_aiH :: GHC.Enum.Enum a_aiG) ->
    GHC.Enum.enumFrom @ a_aiG $dEnum_aiH (GHC.Err.undefined @ a_aiG)

X.aoeu :: forall t_aiS. GHC.Enum.Enum t_aiS => [t_aiS]
[GblId, Arity=1]
X.aoeu =
  \ (@ t_aiV) ($dEnum_aiW :: GHC.Enum.Enum t_aiV) ->
    GHC.Enum.enumFrom @ t_aiV $dEnum_aiW (GHC.Err.undefined @ t_aiV)
```

so the *only* difference between these two representations is the assigned type variable name. I don't know enough about how GHC works to know where that `t` comes from, but at least I've narrowed it down!

---

Ørjan Johansen has noted in a comment that something similar seems to happen with function definitions and lambda abstractions.

```
Prelude> :t \x -> x
\x -> x :: t -> t
```

but

```
Prelude> :t map (\x->x) $ undefined
map (\x->x) $ undefined :: [b]
```

In the latter case, the type `b` comes from an explicit type signature given to `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the concepts of [alpha equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence) and [alpha substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B1-conversion)?  This captures the notion that, for example, both of the following are completely equivalent and interconvertible (in certain circumstances) even though they differ:

```
\x -> (x, x)
\y -> (y, y)
```

The same concept can be extended to the level of types and type variables (see "System F" for further reading).  Haskell in fact has a notion of "lambdas at the type level" for binding type variables, but it's hard to see because they're implicit by default.  However, you can make them explicit by using the `ExplicitForAll` extension, and play around with explicitly binding your type variables:

```
ghci> :set -XExplicitForAll 
ghci> let f x = x; f :: forall a. a -> a
```

In the second line, I use the `forall` keyword to introduce a new type variable, which is then used in a type.

In other words, it doesn't matter whether you choose `a` or `t` in your example, as long as the type expressions satisfy alpha-equivalence.  Choosing type variable names so as to maximize human convenience is an entirely different topic, and probably far more complicated!